# can't connect to mysql db in workbench but i can connect to db in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i set up a MySQL database in xampp and i can access it in phpmyadmin but i cant access it in MySQL workbench  or in c# code  . i gave access in my router to port :3306 4403, 80 but still i can't access db in workbench

```
 string myConnection = " datasource= (myip) ; port=3306;username=user;password=pass";
```

and the error is : "unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts"

if it can connect to db in phpmyadmin should'nt it also connect in mysql workbench or c# code ?

Comment: Have you tried to connect locally (mysql server and workbench on the same machine)? AFAIK, mysql server by default only listens on loopback, so a remote connection requires further configuration.

Comment: yes i tried and it works , but i cant connect from my ip , but i access the db in xampp

Answer (score 0):

try "localhost" | "127.0.0.1" instead of your machine IP. if it works then put an entry for your IP which maps to localhost in hosts file, so then you can give your mapped IP in your connection string.

Comment: Please look at the below link for adding an entry in host file

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file

Answer (score 0):

You must configure mysql to listen to any IP:

First, locate the `my.cnf` file, inside, edit the following line:

```
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
```

Also, comment out the following line if present:

```
# skip-networking
```

Restart mysql service and try again

Comment: where to find my.cnf file ?

Comment: If in Windows, probably under `C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf`

Comment: there is only my.ini file , is that it ?

Comment: Probably yes. Search for the `bind-address` inside to make sure

Comment: Did you check your windows firewall settings? It could be rejecting the incoming connections.

Comment: inbound or outbound ?

Comment: Inbound in the mysql server, outbound on your benchmark machine.

Comment: You would need to check mysql logs (`C:/xampp/mysql/data/mysql.log` or similar) and I would recommend trying to check whether it is a mysql error (mysql refuses the connection actively) or a TCP problem (packets do not get delivered) by doing some TCP captures (you could use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html).

Comment: what does it mean if i can enter mysql in phpmyadmin and can't in mysql workbech ?

Comment: In the user table of mysql, you must specify both the user and the origin IP it will be connecting, so there could be a user which is allowed to be used only from localhost. Try running `SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;`. That's what I was implying whether it is a mysql thing or a network problem.